# How to load several hierarchical categories from functions.php

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, functions, actions, hierarchical

I need to insert several categories (about 400) into my site. The categories are hierarchical.

I would like to load them from functions.php but now I can add one category at time, like this:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'load_categories');
function load_categories(){
$cat = array(
    'cat_ID' => 0,
    'cat_name' => 'Personale',
    'category_description' => 'La mia categoria',
    'category_nicename' => 'personale',
    'category_parent' => 0,
    'taxonomy' => 'category' 
);
wp_insert_category($cat);
}
```

I would check if category exist and, if not, add it.

My hierarchical structure is like this:

- category
- - sub-parent-category
- - - sub-sub-parent-category

Is this a best practise to load category by functions.php with admin_init action?

I'm sorry but I'm in developer phase at the time and often I clean the database due to tests

Answer (score 1):

[image: BlukPress Plugin]

Did you try [BulkPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/bulkpress/)?

Easily add and manage multiple categories, pages, custom taxonomy terms and custom post type posts. Create and reorder terms

Comment: It is good but what happen if I delete my db? I have to repopulate by hand, is it? I need something works like automatic script.

Comment: read this [How to Export a List of Categories From WordPress](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/export-list-categories-wordpress-51305.html)